# dismissViewControllerAnimated: completion: happens instantly unless I kludge it

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a custom UIViewController that's being displayed modally. I'm calling it `mainMenu`.

It has its own cute little transition animation it does to make its views slide off screen. When I want to dismiss it, I want to call the custom animation and then actually dismiss it once that's done. It seems like this should work:

```
- (void) dismissCustomViewController {
    [mainMenu slideMenuPanelsAway];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

However, this makes the view controller vanish instantly, before I get to see the custom slidey stuff.

What's the right way to make the view controller wait until the menus are gone before vanishing?

I've tried a bunch of things. I only found one way to make it work:

```
- (void) dismissCustomViewController {
    [mainMenu slideMenuPanelsAway];
    [self performSelector:@selector(dismissController) withObject:nil 
       afterDelay: 2.0f];
}
```

(I wrote a custom method called `dismissController` just to make the selector easier to use, it basically just calls `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`.)

It just seems awful kludgey to use a manual delay setting instead of actually basing it on the completion of the animation. There's got to be a better way, doesn't there?

Comment: Where is your animation code? If you want to do something at the completion of the animation you'll have to put it there.

Comment: I think that's true in some cases, but it doesn't seem true in this one. In fact, if I put the dismissal at the end of the method that conducts the animation, I get the same problem: the dismissal happens instantly and the animation is never seen. I did try this as one of the "bunch of things".

Answer (score 3):

Use animateWithDuration:animations:completion:, and do the "slidey stuff" in the animation block and do the dismissal in the completion block.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        //Your custom animation stuff here

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
```

Comment: Doesn't this only work if the animations are actual UIView animations? Because they're not.

Comment: @LeMotJuiced, what kind of animations are they? You said you were sliding views.

Comment: They're sliding views that don't use UIView animations. They use NDA methods.

Comment: @LeMotJuiced, What is an NDA method?

Comment: A method I am not at liberty to discuss because I am bound by NDA.